# What's the usage of expression of "Stand on feet"?

Tags: vocabulary, slang

I found on internet dictionaries that "Stand on (own) feet" means "to be independent, financial self-supporting". 
But I was wondering if they could mean also "to rise from a seated position".
I figure this kind of question isn't likely to be solved by dictionaries.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As OP has already discovered, [*to stand on one's own (two) feet*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stand-on-ones-own-two-feet) is an idiomatically established metaphoric usage meaning *to be independent* (usually, but not necessarily, *financially* independent).

But although it might seem tautologous to include both *stand* and *feet* when used "literally", it's by no means uncommon. My guess is most of almost 20,000 written instances of [*stand on your feet*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stand%20on%20your%20feet%22) are either completely literal or nearly so (it's often used to imply *Get up and **do** something to resolve a problem*, as opposed to simply *Rise from a seated position*).

---

I would tend to draw a distinction between...

> 1: *I've been [standing on my feet all day](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22been%20standing%20on%20my%20feet%20all%20day%22)*
>      ...and...
>    2: *I've been [standing all day](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22been%20standing%20all%20day%22)*
>    ...both of which are far less common than...
>    3: *I've been [on my feet all day](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22been%20on%20my%20feet%20all%20day%22)*

One significant difference is that #2 often occurs in contexts where I've been *standing around **waiting** for something* (by implication, standing in order to be better able to react quickly when it *does* happen).

But another difference is that although it's relatively less common, #1 strongly implies that I've been standing *in the same place* all day, as a consequence of which my feet are aching. On the other hand, #3 strongly implies that I've been *moving around from place to place a lot* - as a consequence of which I might feel ["rushed off my feet"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rush-run-sb-off-their-feet) (I'm physically and mentally tired all over, it's not just my feet that ache).

Thus #1 would be more likely from, say, a sales assistant who's been *standing in one place* behind a shop counter serving customers. #3 seems more appropriate for, say, a postman who's been *walking* all day, delivering the mail.

But #2 has neither of those implications, and it may be useful to note that *I've been [been standing **here** all day](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22been%20standing%20here%20all%20day%22)* is actually more common than the simpler version in my numbered link above. And in the vast majority of cases it's not really "literal" at all - there's usually an implicit or explicit reference to either *standing around waiting* or *doing nothing in particular, just standing around idly*.

---

For the literal sense in imperative contexts, you're more likely to hear ***Get*** [up] on your feet! from a speaker urging his audience to rise from a seated position (assuming *feet* are to be referenced at all).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it could be used that way, but I can't imagine a native English speaker ever doing so.

If it were used literally, it would be tautologous, because if we are standing, we must be on our own feet. So the only circumstance in which anybody is likely to say "stand on my/his/her/your own [two] feet" is when it is being used figuratively.

Notice also that the verb "stand" has two meanings, a static one ("be standing up") and a dynamic one ("rise to a standing position"). The latter is usually "stand up", but it can be just "stand", especially in more formal contexts. "Stand on your own two feet" to me strongly implies the static meaning - perhaps because the primary meaning of "on" is static - whereas your suggested meaning is the dynamic one.

Comment: I just want to add: The phrase "Get up; stand on your feet" _could_ be used literally, especially in a chastising way. (I can see a coach saying that to a player, or a parent saying that to a child who is being lazy or disrespectful.) That said, I'm not disagreeing this answer, because I **do** have trouble imagining myself adding the words "own" or "two" into the expression unless I was using the more figurative meaning of the phrase.

Comment: And yet, it's still the first callback in the Rocky Horror Picture Show:
"Lips: Michael Rennie was ill/The Day the Earth Stood Still/But he told us where we stand.[On our feet!]"